# How do you link to an action that takes an array as a parameter (RedirectToAction and/or ActionLink)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, actionlink, redirecttoaction

I have an action defined like so:

```
public ActionResult Foo(int[] bar) { ... }
```

Url's like this will work as expected:

```
.../Controller/Foo?bar=1&bar=3&bar=5
```

I have another action that does some work and then redirects to the `Foo` action above for some computed values of `bar`.

Is there a simple way of specifying the route values with RedirectToAction or ActionLink so that the url's get generated like the above example?

These don't seem to work:

```
return RedirectToAction("Foo", new { bar = new[] { 1, 3, 5 } });
return RedirectToAction("Foo", new[] { 1, 3, 5 });

<%= Html.ActionLink("Foo", "Foo", new { bar = new[] { 1, 3, 5 } }) %>
<%= Html.ActionLink("Foo", "Foo", new[] { 1, 3, 5 }) %>
```

However, for a single item in the array, these do work:

```
return RedirectToAction("Foo", new { bar = 1 });
<%= Html.ActionLink("Foo", "Foo", new { bar = 1 }) %>
```

When setting bar to an array, it redirects to the following:

```
.../Controller/Foo?bar=System.Int32[]
```

Finally, this is with ASP.NET MVC 2 RC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do this. If you want to keep it stateless avoid using 
TempData and create a action filter.

Somthing like this:

ActionFilter:

```
public class BindArrayAttribute:ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var keys = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Where(p => p.StartsWith("id"));

        var idArray = new int[keys.Count()];

        var counter = 0;
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            var id = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[key];
            idArray[counter] = int.Parse(id);
            counter++;
        }

        filterContext.ActionParameters["id"] = idArray;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ItemModel model)
    {
        var dic = new RouteValueDictionary();

        var counter = 0;
        foreach (var id in model.SelectedItemIds)
        {
            dic.Add("id" + counter, id);
            counter++;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Display", dic);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [BindArray]
    public ActionResult Display(int[] id = null)
    {
        return View(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to accomplish that using the existing helpers.  But you could write your own method to do so.

Here's something I threw together:

```
    public static string EnumerableActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string controllerName, string actionName, IEnumerable enumerable, string variableName)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder(string.Format("/{0}/{1}?", controllerName, actionName));

        foreach (var item in enumerable)
            builder.Append(string.Format("{0}={1}&", variableName, item));

        return string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", builder, linkText);
    }
```

Usage example:

```
<%= Html.EnumerableActionLink("Foo", "Foo", "Foo", new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, "bar")%>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Foo", "Foo", "Foo", 
    new[] { 1, 3, 5 }.Aggregate(string.Empty, (a, x) => a += "bar=" + x + "&"))
%>
```