# Redirect to action with querystring array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to do a redirect to action with a querystring array:

```
string[] variantIds = new { 
  "test1",
  "test2",
};

return RedirectToAction("SamplesOrderStep3", new { variantIds });
```

But this redirects to

```
sample-order-step3?variantIds=System.String%5B%5D
```

How do I get it to go to

```
sample-order-step3?variantIds=test1&variantIds=test2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are unable to redirect directly using redirect to action - in the end I used a mixture or `Url.Action` and `Redirect`:

```
return Redirect($"{Url.Action("SamplesOrderStep3")}?variantIds={string.Join("&variantIds=", variantIds)}");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this ['How do you link to an action that takes an array as a parameter (RedirectToAction and/or ActionLink)?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450901/how-do-you-link-to-an-action-that-takes-an-array-as-a-parameter-redirecttoactio) describes your situation, [Lee Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180329/lee-smith) answer seems similar and useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's better if you convert it to string with a separator

```
string variantIdsString = "test1,test2";
```

Or try to use a list of strings instead of an array.